# Does the latest version of TextIO (2.11 and above) have ability to read lines in parallel from a file?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I read through the splittable DoFn blog and from what I could gather, this feature is already available in TextIO (for Cloud dataflow runner). The thing I am not clear on is - using TextIO will I be able to read lines from a given file in parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For only Java, the TextIO source will automatically read an uncompressed file in parallel.

This isn't officially documented, but the TextIO source is a subclass of the FileBaseSource that allows seeking. Meaning that if the worker decides to split the work, it can do so. See the code for FileBasedSource splitting [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileBasedSource.java#L251-L299).

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Cubez is good. I would also like to add that TextIO being both a PTransform and I/O connector has the expand() method implemented:

```
@Override
public PCollection<String> expand(PCollection<FileIO.ReadableFile> input) {
  return input.apply(
      "Read all via FileBasedSource",
      new ReadAllViaFileBasedSource<>(
          getDesiredBundleSizeBytes(),
          new CreateTextSourceFn(getDelimiter()),
          StringUtf8Coder.of()));
}
```

If we look further, we can see that ReadAllViaFileBasedSource class also has expand() method defined as follows:

```
@Override
public PCollection<T> expand(PCollection<ReadableFile> input) {
return input
    .apply("Split into ranges", ParDo.of(new SplitIntoRangesFn(desiredBundleSizeBytes)))
    .apply("Reshuffle", Reshuffle.viaRandomKey())
    .apply("Read ranges", ParDo.of(new ReadFileRangesFn<>(createSource)))
    .setCoder(coder);
```

}

This is how the underlying runner may distribute the PCollection across executors and read in parallel.